# Union on Graph Data in Mathematica

Tags: graph-theory, mathematica

I have begun working with Mathematica for some Graph Theory, and I want to compute the number of spanning trees of all cubic graphs up to 12 vertices. I have found that

GraphData["Cubic", 12]

will give me the cubic graphs with 12 vertices. But how do I compute the number of spanning trees in each of these graphs. A good tutorial for Graph Theory with Mathematica seems impossible to find (I have found many, but none are actually readable). I can find this:

GraphData[8];
Union[GraphData[#, "VertexCount"] & /@ %%]

to compute the number of vertices in all graphs on 8 vertices, but the #-tag is not defined, and &/@%% seems pretty magical.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to be able to exclude graphs which are not connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help figure out a Mathematica expression, following is useful

```
GraphData[8]; Union[GraphData[#, "VertexCount"] & /@ %%] // Hold // TreeForm
```

Also, try `FullForm` instead of `TreeForm`

Since `GraphData` has property `SpanningTreeCount`, you could do

```
graphs = GraphData[{"Cubic", "Connected"}, 12];
counts = GraphData[#, "SpanningTreeCount"] & /@ graphs;
Column@Thread@{counts, graphs}
```

Alternatively, you could get number of spanning trees from Laplacian matrix of the graph using [Kirchoff's matrix tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem).

```
kirk[L_] := Det@Drop[L, {1}, {1}];
counts = kirk[GraphData[#, "LaplacianMatrix"]] & /@ graphs;
```

The `Drop` command drops 1st row and 1st column of the matrix, but you could drop any other row/column.

To display 12 vertex cubic graphs nicely, with graph name in tooltip and sorted by number of spanning trees, you could do something like this

```
count[name_] := GraphData[name, "SpanningTreeCount"];
showCount[name_] := Show[GraphData@name, PlotLabel -> count@name];
showLabeledCount[name_] := Tooltip[showCount@name, name];
graphs = GraphData["Cubic", 12];
pics = showLabeledCount /@ Sort[graphs, count[#1] < count[#2] &];
pics = ArrayPad[pics, {0, 2}, Graphics[]];
GraphicsGrid@Partition[pics, 10]
```

[image]

To get all cubic, connected graphs with **up to** 12 vertices (disconnected graphs are not interesting since they have 0 spanning trees), do `GraphData[{"Cubic", "Connected"}, ;; 12]`

If you are doing graph theory with Mathematica, you could find my graph utilities [packages](http://yaroslavvb.com/blog/Bulatov-sdp.zip) helpful, documented [here](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/01/listing-all-hamiltonian-cycles-of-graph.html), [here](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/02/chordal-graph-usage.html), and [here](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/01/tree-decomposition-package.html). For instance, with `showGraphs` package, you could display all Cubic graphs over 12 vertices that are not connected with `showGraphs[12,"Cubic",!"Connected"]`

Comment: markdown doesn't recognize link to wikipedia's Kirkhoff's theorem because it has an apostrophe in it, any idea how to make the link work?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's pick apart the command you mention.

```
Union[GraphData[#, "VertexCount"] & /@ %%]
```

`GraphData[#, "VertexCount"]&` is the same as `Function[x, GraphData[x, "VertexCount"]]`.  That is, the `#` is an input parameter and the `&` terminates the expression of the `#` parameter to be considered a function.  `%%` is the result-before-last (`%` is the most recent result, `%%` is the one before that, `%%%` is the one before that one, etc.).  `/@` applies a function to each item of a list.  So, `GraphData[#, "VertexCount"] & /@ %%` returns the list that results from applying the function `GraphData[#, "VertexCount"]&` to each element of the list in `%%`.  Because of the `%%`, the line

```
GraphData[8]; Union[GraphData[#, "VertexCount"] & /@ %%]
```

is probably out of context (since `%%` should refer to the result of the statement before `GraphData[8]`), and beyond saying that `Union[]` gives the union of sets, I can't tell what it's doing here because I don't know to what `%%` refers.

---

Now, back to what you're trying to do.  `GraphData[some_graph, "SpanningTreeCount"]` will give the number of spanning trees for *some_graph* (I think, based on the documentation for `GraphData`), so `GraphData[#, "SpanningTreeCount"] & /@ GraphData["Cubic", 12]` will give a list containing the number of spanning trees for each of the cubic graphs with 12 vertices, and

```
Total[GraphData[#, "SpanningTreeCount"] & /@ GraphData["Cubic", 12]]
```

will give the total of the numbers in that list.

Also, since `GraphData[#, "Connected"]&` is a function that returns `True` for connected graphs and `False` otherwise,

```
Select[GraphData["Cubic", 12], GraphData[#, "Connected"] &]
```

will give you a list of only the connected cubic graphs with 12 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IGSpanningTreeCount` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) to count spanning trees in a graph using Mathematica.

```
IGSpanningTreeCount /@ GraphData /@ GraphData["Cubic", 12]

(* {0, 0, 0, 2112, 2640, 2520, 2808, 3584, 4360, 4080, 4608, \
4096, 3840, 5184, 5104, 5544, 4720, 3072, 4480, 5016, 5368, 5632, \
4992, 5824, 5712, 5250, 4875, 5535, 4500, 5130, 6580, 6555, 6435, \
7050, 6240, 6885, 6875, 7003, 7344, 6320, 7520, 7485, 6765, 7392, \
7569, 7467, 7280, 7797, 8165, 7840, 6771, 8131, 6720, 7424, 8323, \
8284, 7300, 8100, 7140, 7280, 8256, 6912, 5832, 7560, 7938, 8103, \
8736, 8901, 8580, 8820, 8950, 9000, 9170, 8960, 9291, 9240, 9464, \
9568, 9800, 9747, 0, 0, 0, 8640, 7350, 9216, 6235, 0, 8112, 8100, 0, \
8640, 6000, 0} *)
```

You may also find `IGKRegularGame` useful which can be used to generate random cubic graphs (note that the sampling is not uniform, but the function is quite fast).

Here's a 100-node one:

```
IGKRegularGame[100, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[%]

(* 91662961107198066022274092725381107 *)
```